# how to delete firstdigit 0 from date and month

Tags: php, date

Code:

```
$today_mem = date("d.m");
echo $today_mem; // -> 15.02
```

I need to transform dates like 15.02 into 15.2, also need to transform for ex. 07.02 into 7.2 and so on every day.
So the question is: how to delete firstdigit 0 from date and month.
Any short solutions?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You'll want to use:

```
$today_mem = date("j.n");
echo $today_mem; // -> 15.2
```

To remove the leading zeros. See more format modifiers at: [php.net/date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 31):

Use `j` instead of `d` and `n` instead of `m`:

```
$today_mem = date("j.n");
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) at the PHP doc site.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$today_mem = date("j")
```

Comment: As opposed to `j.n` in the other answers? Why?